# pipe write and read error in c: program freeze up

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, pipe, valgrind

I am running the c code with multiprocessing by `fork`, and use the pipe to make child processes communicate with the parent process.

But when running the `write` part, let's say 3 out of 13 processes were succeeded, and then the program was just frozen up, which means, it couldn't go any further, neither `segmentation fault`, nor stopped anyhow.

I could not use `gdb` to debug, even with `set follow-fork-mode child`, or `Valgrind`, the program was simply frozen.

The codes are as following:

1. Function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


struct IntArrLen {
 int length;
 int index;
 int* arr;
};

struct IntArrLenArr {
 struct IntArrLen *intArrLen;
 int max_index;
 int length;
};

void write_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len){
    char *p = buffer;
    while(len > 0){
        size_t wlen = write(fd, p, len);
        if(wlen <= 0){
            printf("Error when writing.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        p += wlen;
        len -= wlen;
    }
}

void write_intArrLen(int fd, struct IntArrLen *p){
    write_check(fd, &p->index, sizeof(p->index));
    write_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    write_check(fd, p->arr, p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
}


void write_intArrLenArr(int fd, struct IntArrLenArr *p){
    write_check(fd, &p->max_index, sizeof(p->max_index));
    write_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<p->length; i++)
        write_intArrLen(fd, &p->intArrLen[i]);
}


void read_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len){
    char *p = buffer;
    while (len > 0){
        size_t rlen = read(fd, p, len);
        if(rlen <= 0){
            printf("Error when reading.\n");
     
            exit(0);
        }
        p += rlen;
        len -= rlen;
    }
}

void read_intArrLen(int fd, struct IntArrLen *p){
    read_check(fd, &p->index, sizeof(p->index));
    read_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    p->arr = malloc(p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
    if(!p->arr){
        printf("ran out of memory.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    read_check(fd, p->arr, p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
}

void read_intArrLenArr(int fd, struct IntArrLenArr *p){
    read_check(fd, &p->max_index, sizeof(p->max_index));
    read_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    p->intArrLen = malloc(p->length * sizeof(*p->intArrLen));
    if(!p->intArrLen){
        printf("ran out of memoty.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<p->length; i++)
        read_intArrLen(fd, &p->intArrLen[i]);
}

struct IntArrLenArr getRes(int num1, int num2){
    struct IntArrLenArr ret;
    ret.length = num1;
    ret.max_index = num2;
    ret.intArrLen = malloc(sizeof(struct IntArrLen) * num1);
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<num1; i++){
        ret.intArrLen[i].length = num1;
        ret.intArrLen[i].index = num2;
        ret.intArrLen[i].arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * num1);
        for(j=0; j<num2; j++){
            ret.intArrLen[i].arr[j] = j;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


int main(void){

    struct IntArrLenArr res;
    res.max_index = 0;
    res.length = 0;
    int i;

    pid_t child_pid;
    int *fds = malloc(sizeof(int) * 13 * 2);

    for(i=0; i<13; i++){
        if(pipe(fds + i*2) <0)
            exit(0);
    }

    for(i=0; i<13; i++){
        //fflush(NULL);
        child_pid =fork();
        if(child_pid == 0){
            close(fds[i*2]);
            res = getRes(20, 3000000); // 300,000 works but not with 3000,000
            if(res.length != 0){
                printf("-----------%d\n", i);
                write_intArrLenArr(fds[i*2+1], &res);
                printf("+++++++++++%d\n", i);
            }
            close(fds[i*2+1]);
            exit(0);
        }else if(child_pid == -1){
            printf("fork error\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<13; i++){
        close(fds[i*2+1]);
        read_intArrLenArr(fds[i*2], &res);
        printf(".................%d\n", i);
        if (res.length > 0){
            printf("do something\n");
       }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

`res` above like something like this:

```
res -> length: 20
    -> max_index: 458965845
    -> IntArrLen: -> IntArrLen[0] -> length: 125465
                                  -> index: 45687987
                                  -> int * arr: 123,1565,48987,45879,... // 125465 numbers
                  -> IntArrLen[1] -> length: 5465798956
                                  -> index: 34579999
                                  -> int * arr: 78123,1565,48987,45879,... // 5465798956 numbers
                  -> IntArrLen[2] -> length: 5465798956
                                  -> ....
                  -> ...
```

Could anybody help me to find out what is wrong here? Or is there any other way that I can somehow debug the code? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Show all the code.  Nowhere in the shown code for `fun1` does the parent close any of the pipes.  Perhaps that happens in the code you didn't disclose.

Comment: Probably the parent is blocking on a read from the pipes, and the read will never return because the parent sill has the write sides open.  But: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @WilliamPursell Hi, thanks for your answer. I have added the reading part to the code.

Comment: This code is still unusable.  There is no opening bracket on the function definiton, and no closing bracket, and no return statement.  If someone can cut-n-paste your code into a shell, they are far more likely to help.  I am not willing to cut-n-paste from several different windows *and* edit the code just to get it to build.

Comment: There's no `main()` function, and you've left out all the headers. There are no declarations for the functions but functions must be defined or declared before they are used.  When you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name — then maybe we can help.  Until then, you're mostly on your own. NB: `getRes()` is not defined, and `do something` in `if (res.length > 0){ do something }` is not valid C.

Comment: Also, error messages should be written to `stderr` and not `stdout`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hey, thanks for your answer, I will add the headers and so on, but for example, the `getRes()` was really a rabbit hole function that I don't know how to make an MCVE version.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Hey, I rewrote it and now it can be run without pain, could you please look at it again. I found that if the parameters passing to `getRes()` are too large, that will cause problems, is there a limit for `pipe` or something? because the value return from `getRes()` can be really huge like over several MB in real life.

Comment: Learn about [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)s using something like [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Use also other [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/). See also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Comment: Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). It is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) and you are allowed to download it and improve it. Don't forget to use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before your [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) - which could fail

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I read that fflush is being used for refreshing in/output stream buffer, but in my case, the data are written to different pipes and later would be read out. I don't get where shall I put the flush there?

Comment: Use `fflush(NULL)` it would flush all output streams, include `stdout` & `stderr`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch directly before `fork()`? I did it so, but it didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: Which platform are you working on?  On Unix-like systems, using `void` for the return type of `main()` is unconditionally wrong (on Windows, you can sorta get away with it, but it still isn't particularly good practice).  You've got `void main(int argc, char **argv)` but you never reference either argument; you should use `int main(void)`.  You've omitted `#include <unistd.h>` so you don't have declarations for `pipe()` or `read()` or `write()`.  If your compiler isn't complaining about the undeclared functions, turn up the warning level, or specify C18, C11, C99, or get a better compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the compiler I am using is `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
`

Comment: I'm familiar with that beastie (GCC 4.8.5); it's the default system compiler on one of the main machines I work on at work.  I've just finished installing GCC 10.3.0 on the same machine.   I use the options `-O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common` for code for/from SO questions.  For my own code, I use `-g -O3 -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wold-style-definition -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes`.  (I should upgrade to C18 sometime — but the differences between C11 and C18 are minimal.)

Comment: With `#include <unistd.h>`, declaring all functions first and fixing the signature of `main()` to `int main(void)`, the code only complains about three unused variables (`j`, `status` and `wpid`).  With those fixed, it compiles cleanly enough to satisfy me.  I'll try to look at the code later, but at least it is reasonably compilable now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But I guess there are still problems when running the code right?

Comment: Most likely; I've not got around to running it yet.  _[…time passeth — but not very much of it…]_  When I run the program `./pipe53` it gives just `Error when reading`.  I've not tracked down why.  You don't process arguments, so it can't be that.  Presumably, it means a read from a pipe failed, but I know not why yet.  Note that the return value from `read()` is a `ssize_t` (two s's).  You assign to a `size_t` (one s).  That can never be negative.  It's conventional to exit with a non-zero status when you detect an error — use `exit(0)` or equivalent only when the program succeeds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, the same error to me as well, I only know if the second parameter passing to `getRes()` is reduced to 300000, the problem would be gone. I think there is a good chance that it is the same problem as in my original code. Because of the massive data

Comment: Don't forget to compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But it still shows me the reading error :/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added the `errno` behind where `Error when reading` is printed out. but the `errno` was 0

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  Hey, I found the error so far, but thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dereived this code from the code in the question (source file `pipe53.c` compiled to the executable `pipe53`):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct IntArrLen
{
    int length;
    int index;
    int *arr;
};

struct IntArrLenArr
{
    struct IntArrLen *intArrLen;
    int max_index;
    int length;
};

static size_t bytes_allocated = 0;

struct IntArrLenArr getRes(int num1, int num2);
void read_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len);
void read_intArrLen(int fd, struct IntArrLen *p);
void read_intArrLenArr(int fd, struct IntArrLenArr *p);
void write_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len);
void write_intArrLen(int fd, struct IntArrLen *p);
void write_intArrLenArr(int fd, struct IntArrLenArr *p);

static void fd_close(int fd)
{
    close(fd);
    //fprintf(stderr, "%d: closing %d\n", (int)getpid(), fd);
}

static void report_memory_used(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: bytes allocated = %zu\n", (int)getpid(), bytes_allocated);
}

static void *memory_allocator(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *vp = malloc(nbytes);
    bytes_allocated += nbytes;
    report_memory_used();       // Dire straights!
    return vp;
}

void write_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len)
{
    char *p = buffer;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: writing %zu bytes to fd %d\n",
            (int)getpid(), len, fd);
    while (len > 0)
    {
        ssize_t wlen = write(fd, p, len);
        if (wlen <= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: Error when writing fd = %d.\n",
                    (int)getpid(), fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        p += wlen;
        len -= wlen;
    }
}

void write_intArrLen(int fd, struct IntArrLen *p)
{
    write_check(fd, &p->index, sizeof(p->index));
    write_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    write_check(fd, p->arr, p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
}

void write_intArrLenArr(int fd, struct IntArrLenArr *p)
{
    write_check(fd, &p->max_index, sizeof(p->max_index));
    write_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    for (int i = 0; i < p->length; i++)
        write_intArrLen(fd, &p->intArrLen[i]);
}

void read_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len)
{
    char *p = buffer;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        ssize_t rlen = read(fd, p, len);
        if (rlen < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: Error %d (%s) when reading fd = %d.\n",
                   (int)getpid(), errno, strerror(errno), fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (rlen == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: Premature EOF when reading fd = %d.\n",
                    (int)getpid(), fd);
            break;
        }
        p += rlen;
        len -= rlen;
    }
}

void read_intArrLen(int fd, struct IntArrLen *p)
{
    read_check(fd, &p->index, sizeof(p->index));
    read_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    p->arr = memory_allocator(p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
    if (!p->arr)
    {
        printf("ran out of memory.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: ran out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n",
                (int)getpid(), p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    read_check(fd, p->arr, p->length * sizeof(*p->arr));
}

void read_intArrLenArr(int fd, struct IntArrLenArr *p)
{
    read_check(fd, &p->max_index, sizeof(p->max_index));
    read_check(fd, &p->length, sizeof(p->length));
    p->intArrLen = memory_allocator(p->length * sizeof(*p->intArrLen));
    if (!p->intArrLen)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: ran out of memory (%zu bytes requested)\n",
                (int)getpid(), p->length * sizeof(*p->intArrLen));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < p->length; i++)
        read_intArrLen(fd, &p->intArrLen[i]);
}

struct IntArrLenArr getRes(int num1, int num2)
{
    struct IntArrLenArr ret;
    ret.length = num1;
    ret.max_index = num2;
    ret.intArrLen = memory_allocator(sizeof(struct IntArrLen) * num1);
    if (ret.intArrLen == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n",
                (int)getpid(), sizeof(struct IntArrLen) * num1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
    {
        ret.intArrLen[i].length = num1;
        ret.intArrLen[i].index = num2;
        ret.intArrLen[i].arr = memory_allocator(sizeof(int) * num1);
        if (ret.intArrLen[i].arr == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n",
                    (int)getpid(), sizeof(int) * num1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++)
        {
            ret.intArrLen[i].arr[j] = j;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct IntArrLenArr res;
    res.max_index = 0;
    res.length = 0;

    atexit(report_memory_used);

    printf("Parent process: %d\n", (int)getpid());

    int *fds = memory_allocator(sizeof(int) * 13 * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(fds + i * 2) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to create pipe %d\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0)
        {
            printf("%d: Child process: %d - pipe [%d,%d]\n",
                    (int)getpid(), i, fds[i * 2 + 0], fds[i * 2 + 1]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
            {
                fd_close(fds[j * 2 + 0]);
                if (i != j)
                    fd_close(fds[j * 2 + 1]);
            }
            //res = getRes(20, 3000000); // 300,000 works but not with 3000,000
            res = getRes(20, 300000); // 300,000 works but not with 3000,000
            report_memory_used();
            if (res.length != 0)
            {
                printf("-----------%d\n", i);
                write_intArrLenArr(fds[i * 2 + 1], &res);
                printf("+++++++++++%d\n", i);
            }
            fd_close(fds[i * 2 + 1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (child_pid == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: launched child %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)child_pid);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        fd_close(fds[i * 2 + 1]);
        read_intArrLenArr(fds[i * 2 + 0], &res);
        printf(".................%d\n", i);
        if (res.length > 0)
        {
            printf("do something\n");
        }
        fd_close(fds[i] * 2 + 0);
    }

    free(fds);
    return 0;
}
```

An example of the output I get from running it (on a MacBook Pro) is:

```
$ ./pipe53 2>&1 | cat           # I actually pipe the output to "so | pbcopy" …
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: launched child 23383
23380: launched child 23384
23383: bytes allocated = 424
23383: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23385
23384: bytes allocated = 424
23384: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23386
23385: bytes allocated = 424
23385: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23387
23386: bytes allocated = 424
23386: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23388
23387: bytes allocated = 424
23387: bytes allocated = 504
23388: bytes allocated = 424
23388: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23389
23380: launched child 23390
23389: bytes allocated = 424
23389: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23391
23390: bytes allocated = 424
23390: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23392
23391: bytes allocated = 424
23391: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23393
23392: bytes allocated = 424
23392: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23394
23393: bytes allocated = 424
23393: bytes allocated = 504
23380: launched child 23395
23394: bytes allocated = 424
23394: bytes allocated = 504
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 3.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 3.
23395: bytes allocated = 424
23395: bytes allocated = 504
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 5.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 5.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 7.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 7.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 9.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 9.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 11.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 11.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 13.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 13.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 15.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 15.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 17.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 17.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 19.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 19.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 21.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 21.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 23.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 23.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 25.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 25.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 27.
23380: Premature EOF when reading fd = 27.
23380: bytes allocated = 104
23380: bytes allocated = 104
Parent process: 23380
.................0
.................1
.................2
.................3
.................4
.................5
.................6
.................7
.................8
.................9
.................10
.................11
.................12
```

AFAICT, the `getRes()` function (with both size 300,000 and 3,000,000) is not triggering anything being written by the child processes.

Note the careful use of identifying PIDs in the debugging messages.

You need to revise `getRes()` so that it causes data to be written to the parent process.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!!! I used the way you used here and I found the error, indeed there was something wrong with the `getRes()` function. It did help me a lot, thanks man!